# Visual Studio: Detect type presence in a container

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have the following situation: I do serialization of an object: `MyBOContainer`.

It throws me serialization errors "the class `MyUIElement` is not marked as serializable".

Normally, I shouldn't have such a class between `myBOContainer` elements(or their children).
However, I have some public `List<object>` and theoretically this is possible.

**Question:**
How can I test in the Debug Mode in VS if an instance of object `myBOContainer` contains(deepsearch) or not instances of `MyQueryTestClass` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution that worked was to activate the .NET Framework code debug mode.
Then, from the exception stack trace find the function that throw the exception and debug step by step.

Identifying the moment that the exception was thrown I found out that the "alien" who introduced me UserControls in the BO class was the Event, that was used by the UserControl.

Solution - make this event as `[NonSerialized]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't predict what the data is, then IMO you shouldn't be serializing that element.

Since it appears you are using `BinaryFormatter`, perhaps add some `[NonSerialized]`:

```
[NonSerialized]
private List<object> foo = ...
```

Also, *events* are the usual cause of confusion on this; I would annotate any events, too:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler SomeCrazyEvent;
```

or if you are doing explicit event implementations, set `[NonSerialized]` on whatever backing field is holding the `delegate` or `EventHandlerList`.

(well, *strictly speaking* I just wouldn't be using `BinaryFormatter` in the first place - using a serialize that isn't so tied to the internal class structure can only be a good thing; but that is a rant for another day...)

Comment: Mark, thank you for the suggestion. I understand that serialization problem, however I *need* to serialize the List<object>. Normally is supposed that in the list<object> be only serializable members, so I want to detect where is that list with the "alien" object, because I myBOContainer have multiple members and children and I don't know who contains my alien object. I emphasis the question about *member of type T detection*, not *serialization* issue.

Comment: @serhio - you genuinely need to serialize *unknown* data? That seems... unusual. A deep search for an object is painful - reflection all the way, and remember to keep track of what you've seen so you don't loop. No magic tricks here.

Comment: there is no unknown data. Say I have `Person` and its `FavoriteThing` member. This "Thing" can Be a `Cat`, `Dog`, `Pencil` or `Byke`, all of them marked as serializable, but not an `PencilInfoControl` if you know what I mean...

Comment: @serhio - then maybe a `List<T>` where `T` is some known base-class or interface? (base-class tends to work better than interface when serialization is involved)

Comment: @Marc: I don't know how to link all heterogeneous things that could be FavoriteThings, so I just need to detect what object contains my PencilInfoControl, and how do it came in the Person.

Comment: @serhio - as a one-off? or routintely? For a one-off, just trawl it in the IDE by putting a breakpoint just before it fails.

Comment: putting a breakpoint is ok, but now how to identify where is the object, surely, i could manually check each member in the objects property three. this is not quite commode if we have houndreds of items in collections

Comment: I put a breackpoint and tried to identify where was the "alien" is impossible... so many internal members and collections that I can't do it visually... it may take days... maybe debuggind inside framework code could help, but pressing F11 does not enter the framework code

Answer (score 0):

> How can I test in the Debug Mode in VS
>   if an instance of object myBOContainer
>   contains(deepsearch) or not instances
>   of MyQueryTestClass type?

Here is some C# code that does exactly this:

```
if (myBOContainer.OfType<MyQueryTestClass>().Any())
{
    // the container contains an item of type MyQueryTestClass
}
```

So if you have a `List<object>`, then either don't serialize it (use `NonSerializedAttribute` like the others said), or simply remove the items that are not serializable.

```
myList.RemoveAll(myList.OfType<MyNonSerializableClass>());
```

Or perhaps use reflection to see which item is serializable.

### My recommended solution

**Never ever** use a `List<object>` to store random objects. This is usually caused by disregarding strongly-typedness which is always bad in a strongly typed language. Use `List<SomeSpecificType>` instead.

Comment: for BoContainer i don't mean an IEnumerable, but a BO Container, like Shop that contains Products, People(:Customers), Services etc.

Comment: @serhio - It should implement IEnumerable anyway.